# KVM: Reading GDT base and limit value of guest VM on host

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, intel, kvm, hypervisor

In KVM, I am trying to get the base address and the size of the GDT of the guest VM. When I read the value inside the Windows 7 64bit guest VM I get following values: gdt base `0xfffff80003b37000`, gdt limit `0x7f`. These values I read out with gdtr in kernel mode via a driver. However, when I read the value upon a VMEXIT (triggered by SYSCALL) in VMCB where all the values are stored, I get the following (different) values: gdt base `0xFFFFFFFFA03F8060`, gdt limit `0x8060`. I would expect the values to be identical. Is there some kind of translation/calculation that must be done to get the correct value?

I read out the value using following functions in KVM:

```
vmcs_readl(GUEST_GDTR_BASE)
vmcs_read32(GUEST_GDTR_LIMIT)
```

I actually have the same issue with IDTR. However, I am only interested in GDTR. Reading out other registers like CR3, RIP, or RAX work fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the Kernel, you're getting a guest physical address (GPA) while from the hypervisor you're getting a host physical address (HPA).

You can use the KVM function `gfn_to_pfn` defined in `kvm_host.h` to do the translation.